# Spring boot - POST method not allowed

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I'm dwelling with this problem... I have a Spring Boot application wit a S2S communication. I have a `@RestController` method which should accept POST request.

This is the controller

```
@RestController
public class PaymentRestController {

@PostMapping("/util/paymentResponse")
    public void savePaymentResponse(@RequestParam boolean transaction_status, @RequestParam String usedToken,
            @RequestParam String transaction_message, @RequestParam String authCode,
            @RequestParam String transactionCode, @RequestParam String orderId, HttpServletRequest request) {
//business logic
}

}
```

If i hit this link i get a 405 error, method not allowed

At first time i found that the request was blocked by the CSFR Filter which is enabled on the web application, so I have configured my security in this way

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("it.besmart")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalService(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter() {
        SwitchUserFilter filter = new SwitchUserFilter();
        filter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        filter.setSuccessHandler(customSuccessHandler);
        filter.setFailureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler);
        return filter;
    }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            logger.debug("Webapp security configured");


            http

            .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",  "/home", "/contacts", "/faq", "/privacy", "/register", "/registrationConfirm", "/util/**", "/resendRegistrationToken","/park**", "/oauth/authorize", "/error")
                    .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/profile**", "/edit**","/payment**", "/plate**","/notification**", "/addPaymentMethod**", "/logout/impersonate**")
                    .access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('NOPAYMENT')")
                    .antMatchers("/book**", "/manage**")
                    .access("hasRole('USER')")
                    .antMatchers("/admin**", "/login/impersonate**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                    .antMatchers("/updatePassword").hasAuthority("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE")

                    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/?login=login").loginProcessingUrl("/")                   .successHandler(customSuccessHandler).failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler).usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")

                    .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers( "/util**")
                    .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout=true").permitAll()


                    .and().addFilterAfter(switchUserFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);

        }
```

In this way i'm not getting the CSRF token exception, but still getting the 405 error.
It's not even a problem of POST because if i change to GET the request and the mapping, i still take the 405 error... And if i try to send a POST, i see in the header response that the Allowed method is POST, if i send it in GET i see allowed method POST... weird

I don't know where to see...

Comment: just to exclude problems related to security, can you try to add the property management.security.enabled=false to your application.properties and say if it works like that?

Comment: nothing changed... the problem is still there...

Comment: So it doesn't looks a security problem... How do you POST your request? Also, try to add required=false to all your RequestParam, debug the application and put a breakpoint at the first line of your controller.

Comment: like this: @RequestParam(value = "yourParamName", required = false)

Comment: You were right! There was a null parameter! But it's strange i get a 405 error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was that one of the parameter was null.
It has been solved adding required=null at the request parameter annotation, like that:

```
@RequestParam(value = "yourParamName", required = false)
```

this cause a 405, as defined here:

```
6.5.5.  405 Method Not Allowed

The 405 (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method
received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not
supported by the target resource.  The origin server MUST generate an
Allow header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target
resource's currently supported methods.

A 405 response is cacheable by default; i.e., unless otherwise
indicated by the method definition or explicit cache controls (see
Section 4.2.2 of [RFC7234]).
```

when the "target resource" are defined [here:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.1)

Answer (score 11):

In my case the endpoint had ssl on i.e. it was `https`

In Postman I by mistake was using `http`

`http` will work fine for `GET`s but for `POST`s it returns a 405 method not allowed. It has to be `https` if your endpoint expects it to be.

If you have request and response logging turned on in Spring the `POST` endpoint in the above situation will log as follows:

```
[2021-02-26T10:40:07+02:00] (my-app/fffffa343226e) 2021-02-26T08:40:07,915Z (UTC+0) [http-nio-80-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter - Before request [GET /api/v1/my-app, client=1.2.3.4, user=aUser]
[2021-02-26T10:40:07+02:00] (my-app/fffffa343226e) 2021-02-26T08:40:07,915Z (UTC+0) [http-nio-80-exec-6] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
[2021-02-26T10:40:07+02:00] (my-app/fffffa343226e) 2021-02-26T08:40:07,916Z (UTC+0) [http-nio-80-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter - After request [GET /api/v1/my-app, client=1.2.3.4, user=aUser]
```

Comment: This happened me, maybe we should include this cause also in the documentation, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Also remember to check the protocol. In my case it had to be `https` instead of `http`

The error message could certainly be more descriptive!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I a mapping in my controller in the following way:

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/fetch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Long createFetch() throws IOException {
    return fetchService.doFetch();
}
```

If you notice, the above mapping is to `name`, but the requests work with this. Once I apply the same at the `@Controller` level and at method level, I started seeing this error. Setting the path to `value` resolved this.