# "405 method not allowed" react js application in aws amplify

Tags: reactjs, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-amplify

I have a problem deploying a react js application in aws amplify.

When the react application sends a POST request to a backend (spring boot) I receive "405 method not allowed"

Any help !

Spring boot project is deployed in EC2.

```
@PostMapping("/post")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://xxx.amplifyapp.com/")
public HttpStatus post(@RequestBody) {
    .......
}
```

In react i use createProxyMiddleware :

```
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/api', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://ec2-springboot.com:8082/'}));

}
```

Comment: Does your spring boot backend support a POST call on the route you're trying to access? Is CORS enabled in the backend? Hard to tell without more informations.

Comment: Yes, i use CrossOrigin(origins = "https://xxx.amplifyapp.com") in spring boot request. Locally the POST request works

Comment: I add some informations in my post

Comment: well I know too few about spring boot to give an qualified answer. What comes into my mind is: Maybe you should test the CORS with `*` first, to see if this is the error or something else. Also: Can you see in the network tab when opening your react app, that the correct URL is requested? And also: before each post there will be a OPTION request. Maybe this one fails? So make sure to make the CORS settings global instead of only this endpoint? Hope it helps, cheers

Comment: Yes I added "*" in spring boot cors origin.
I think Amplify does not support POST methods.
I have this in the body of  error "headers:
allow: "HEAD, DELETE, GET, PUT" ".
Is there an AMPLIFY configuration to solve this problem?

Comment: I can not think of any problem with AWS amplify, I guess the error is still in your Spring boot app. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546626/spring-boot-post-method-not-allowed

Comment: Are you able to make the POST request from command line? E.g. from curl?

Comment: ousselk Did you fix your problem?