# Spring boot REST API Method Conflict when same url having GET and POST methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, rest, http-headers

I am working on a REST API and having the below issue when it is deployed to the Azure cloud.
There are two REST APIs, one is for GET and one is for POST only difference is the method parameters as below.

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v2")
public class PatientController {

  @GetMapping("/patients/{patientId}/settings")
  Page<PatientDto> getPatient(@PathVariable String patientId, Pageable pageable) {
    return patientService.getPatient(patientId, pageable);
  }


  @PostMapping("/patients/{patientId}/settings")
  PatientDto createPatient(
      @PathVariable String patientId, @Valid @RequestBody PatientRequestDto PatientRequestDto) {
    return patientService.createPatient(patientId, patientRequestDto);
  }
}
```

Now the problem is when I call for the GET method, it returns 405 Method Not Allowed with below as a response header.

```
Response Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2022 12:31:16 GMT
Allow: POST
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
```

It seems like GET and POST methods have conflicts and only the POST method is recognized.
But the strange thing is when I run this on my localhost, it works as expected with http://localhost:8080 but after deploying to the Azure cloud environment, this issue occurs. I am using Springboot 4.7.x.

Appreciate your kind support on this.Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Spring Security?

Comment: Also try enabling more logs using `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` configuration property.

Comment: @ArturasGusevas yes using spring security.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have enabled **Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)**. You need either provide `_csrf` parameter in the request or disable CSRF using Spring Security Configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

See [Spring Security documentation for CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html) for more details.

Comment: It is disabled actually. :) ``    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(it -> {
                    it.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(customAutConverter);
                })
                .authorizeRequests(it -> it.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .cors()
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new AuthFilter(contextHelper), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf()
                .disable();
        return http.build();
    }``

Comment: You can try disabling CORS.

Comment: yes enabled it. I will try it.

Comment: Another possible cause could be wrong protocol - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66382725/224155